# Adding days to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am trying to add `day column` to `date column`. The column which contains days called `new_duration` and the column which contains the date called `return_before` need to added the new duration to return before date.

This is the logic I am trying to implement

The script below have been implemented but I keep getting error

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Read the error message out loud.

Comment: I know my friend it is because the varchar but I was wondering if there is a workaround other than this. I need solution or guide

Comment: cast it to datetime?

Comment: How do I do that? Can you guide me please ?

Comment: You need to get it to the data type that the function expects.

Comment: Like this: 



 SELECT Convert(Varchar(8), DATEADD(day,visa_new_duration,visa_final_depature_dateg), 108), visa_number, visa_new_return_before
 FROM [dbo].[TBL_MQM_NIC_DO_EXTEND_ER_VISA_RESPONSE]
 ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN visa_new_return_before IS NOT NULL
     THEN visa_new_return_before
     ELSE DATEADD(day, visa_new_duration, '2020-08-04')
   END

Comment: It still did not work

Comment: You have to cast/convert your columns *before* you attempt to use it, not afterwards. As an aside consider using the correct datatypes for any future databases you work on - it makes like much easier .

Comment: DATEADD function require 3 argument. The second one must be an integer. You have to convert the second argument to an integer.

Comment: Got it 
Thank you brother

Comment: Fix the schema and just use appropriate data types. A string type is **not** appropriate for a date.

Answer (score 2):

The error is the Dateadd function is expecting an integer value and, as you said, all your datatypes are varchar. Assuming it's a number stored as a string, you can just cast it to an int.

It's not clear why you have your case condition as an order by clause, however what you want I think is along the lines of

```
select visa_number,
IsNull(visa_new_return_before, DateAdd(day, Cast(visa_new_duration as int), visa_final_depature_dateg) ) as visa_new_return_before
from dbo.[_VISA_RESPONSE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your way 
I got an error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Can you provide the table schema and sample data please?

Comment: I have provided an image with sample data above as you requested

Comment: I have provided table scehma as well above

Comment: You appear to have dates stored in multiple formats :-\
Suggest you include an explicit cast, DATEADD(day, visa_new_duration, Cast(visa_final_depature_dateg as datetime)) 
And check you have the right dateformat set.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I see 
You mean I should change the date format in my table as suggested and showen in the link you provided and after I change the date format in my column, it should work ?

Comment: I would recommend not storing dates as varchar strings, but specifiy the dateatype as datetime; if that's not possible in your circumstances then always store the dates as ISO formatted strings, ie, YYYYMMDD - this avoids any ambiguity and unexpected invalid dates based on regional variations.